# particle-system libraries in conjunction with opencl

Tags: opencl, gpgpu, particle-system

For scientific research I need to simulate particles -- muons, which emit photons, and photo-detectors. The emphasis is not on realtime rendering of results (rendering would be a Could-have ), but rather massive amount of particles.

Are there any libraries which can alleviate the burden of writing a 3d scene and collision detection from scratch?

I was thinking of:

- NVIDIA OptiX Ray Tracing engine
- Bullet Physics library
- ...

However I'm pretty new to OpenCL and the particularities of GPU computing <-> Host communication.

Does anyone have experience using the above, or similar? If so, is this overkill for my intended purpose, or in contrast, is it good to start with a library/framework anyway in case the simulations I need to do get more complex?

Comment: how many particles is a massive amount?  (min/max/typical)

Comment: Bullet is a game physics engine.  It models Newtonian physics, not quantum physics, which is what you want.  Not sure about GPGPU support but perhaps you should look at GEANT 4.

Comment: GEANT indeed seems to be the best fit.